# Al generar varios FORM con WHILE el primer FORM no aparece

Tags: php, html5

Lo que trato de hacer es una tabla que con el **while** va generando un `div` que tenga una imagen, `h4`, dos `input` y un botón, donde los `input` van dentro de un **form** con `method POST`, al ejecutarlo el primer campo del **while** no me responde, pero los demás campos generados si hacen lo que deberían (una inserción a la BD).

PD: todo lo genero con una consulta de la misma BD

PD2: me doy cuenta de que no esta el `form` al inspeccionar el código con Chrome

```
<div class="container" >
<div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="MESA" name="MESA" value="<?php echo $MESA ?>">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <div class="row">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#cer" aria-controls="cer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cerveza</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#preparados" aria-controls="preparados" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Preparados</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#comida" aria-controls="comida" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Comida</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="cer">
        <div class="row">

        <?php
        $x=0;
        while($reg=  mysqli_fetch_array($cerveza))
         {
        echo '<div class="col-md-3">';
        echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
        echo '<img src="../Img/'.mb_convert_encoding($reg['URL'], "UTF-8").'" width="160px" height="190px" >';

          echo "<div class='caption'>";
          echo '<h4>'.mb_convert_encoding($reg['PRODUCTO'], "UTF-8")." $".mb_convert_encoding($reg['PRECIO'], "UTF-8"). '.00</h4>';
          echo "<div class='input-group'>";
          echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../Sql/Menu/agregar.php" method="POST">';

         echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" placeholder="NOA-NOA" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);"> 
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value='.$reg['ID_MENU'].' id="pedido" name="pedido" placeholder="NOA-NOA" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);"> ';
        echo '<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">';
        echo '</form>';
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo'</div>';
        echo'</div>';
        if($x==4)
         {
            echo'<br>';
            $x = 0;
         }
            $x++;
         }
         ?>
            </div>  
            </div>
```

Comment: No se entiende bien el planteamiento de tu pregunta: ¿qué es lo que no funciona en sí? ¿se deberían mostrar X formularios pero no se muestran todos? ¿o lo que falla es cuando envías el formulario? Hay otra cosa extraña, declaras el formulario como `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ... ¿por qué, si generalmente los formularios `multipart` son aquellos que tienen inputs normales e inputs que recogen archivos por ejemplo?

Comment: quiero que el while genere los echo pero por alguna razon en el primer campo generado por el while no agrega el <form> y en los demas si

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el bucle WHILE primero comprueba si la condición es verdadera y después ejecuta el código.
Usando un DO WHILE primero ejecuta el código y después verifica si se cumple la condición. Algo así:

```
<?php
    $x=0;
    do

     {
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">';
    echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
    echo '<img src="../Img/'.mb_convert_encoding($reg['URL'], "UTF-8").'" width="160px" height="190px" >';

      echo "<div class='caption'>";
      echo '<h4>'.mb_convert_encoding($reg['PRODUCTO'], "UTF-8")." $".mb_convert_encoding($reg['PRECIO'], "UTF-8"). '.00</h4>';
      echo "<div class='input-group'>";
      echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../Sql/Menu/agregar.php" method="POST">';

     echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" placeholder="NOA-NOA" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);"> 
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value='.$reg['ID_MENU'].' id="pedido" name="pedido" placeholder="NOA-NOA" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);"> ';
    echo '<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo'</div>';
    echo'</div>';
    if($x==4)
     {
        echo'<br>';
        $x = 0;
     }
        $x++;
     }
     while($reg=  mysqli_fetch_array($cerveza))
 ?>
```

Comment: lo cambie como me dices pero el primer campo no genera la consulta sino hasta el segundo, ya mejor lo hare sin el while, haciendo todas las consultas para cada campo, creo que sera lo mejor, igual no son muchas consultas